# Filter Out JQuery Elements Which Have CSS Style display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery

A selector has yielded me a set of elements. Out the set of elements, I have 1 or 2 elements with CSS attribute display:none. I have to remove these elements and get the elements which have display. How can this be done using JQuery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `.filter()`.

```
var displayed = $('mySelector').filter(function() {
    var element = $(this);

    if(element.css('display') == 'none') {
        element.remove();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

This will return all elements from your selector thats attribute `display` is *not* `none`, and remove those who's are.

Comment: Note that this only finds elements that have an explicit `display:none` in their `style` attribute. The `.css()` method doesn't pick up styles that are inherited from style sheets.

Comment: What makes you say this? According to jQuery docs, `.css( )` is the **computed** style property, so it does include inherited styles. Here's a demo to demonstrate that this is true - https://jsfiddle.net/6uncqqk2/

Comment: I could have sworn I've seen questions in the past where it wasn't using the computed style. Maybe I was thinking of code that uses plain JS `element.style.display`.

Answer (score 9):

```
$("selector").is(":visible")
```

You can also filter out the hidden elements in the original selector:

```
$("selector:visible")
```

Comment: I'm currently using this for elements which I toggle between `display: none` and `display: block`; would there be any problems or inconsistency using it for this purpose?

Comment: @Abdul That should be fine. jQuery checks both the `display` and `visibility` properties to check whether an element is visible.

Comment: While this will often achieve the goal, there is one significant difference (besides the fact that it also checks visibility, as mentioned by @Barmar): it will also check the visibility of parent elements. So if you truly want to filter out just the elements with `display: none`, then `:visible` will give false positives.

Comment: I also discovered that :visible returns an incorrect result if run in the same script as the visibility is set.
For example:
`{
$("#el").show();
if ($("#el:visible").length==0) console.log("this is still empty");
}`
But
`{
$("#el").show();
setTimeout(function() {
if ($("#el:visible").length>0) console.log("now it finds it");},0);
}`
Just thought I would mention this here as it took me quite a while to figure it out!

Answer (score 5):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var listWithoutDisplayNone = elementList.filter(function(){
      if($(this).css('display') != 'none')
           return $(this);
});
```